# Passing an array to a function which accepts double pointer in arg-list

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-to-pointer

I want to pass newly defined array `bool myArr[] = { false, false, true };` to below existing function.

```
void fun(bool** pArr, int idx)
{
    if(NULL == *pArr)
       return;

    (*pArr)[idx] = false;

    ...
    ...

    return;
}
```

I am not allowed to change anything in subroutine `fun` and I want to invoke the function by using the identifier `myArr`. When I try `fun(&myArr, 2);` I get below compilation error.

> no matching function for call to `fun(bool (*)[3], int)`
>
> candidates are: void fun(bool**, int)

One way I can think of is as below

```
bool* ptr = myArr;
fun(&ptr, 2);
```

But it looks dirty to me, please suggest a way to invoke `fun` my using the `myArr`

Comment: It looks dirty, what's basically how to do it.

Comment: `if(NULL == *pArr)` uncomfortable is reverse in speaking.

Comment: hacky way of doing it can be `fun((bool **)&myArr, 2);`

Comment: What will happen if the function will decide to assign `*pArr`?? Something fishy with this design. Your "dirty" way is the only right one...

Comment: @SouravGhosh that has no chance of working :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh no `static_cast` or other C++-typed casts? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh See my previous comment

Comment: @iharob: Many people do this because they are afraid of writing `= `instead of `==`. I hate it as well.

Comment: @FrankPuffer It becomes pretty natural once you get used to it if people in your environment are using it.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I know why they do it. But compilers warn about this so it's not necessary anymore, Some: *c standard suggest parentheses around assignments used as truth value* or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Functions that want a pointer to a pointer typically expect a *[jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).* You can construct an array of arrays with a single element `myArray`, and pass that array to your function, like this:

```
bool *arrayOfPtrs[] = { myArray };
fun(arrayOfPtrs, 2);
```

This reads slightly better than your pointer solution, because creating an array of pointers eliminates the question of why you are creating a pointer to a pointer ([demo](http://ideone.com/WJ3SQM)).

Comment: A link to the term *jagged array* would be nice. I suspect it's something I would use with *libmysqlclient* if I had to bind a single parameter or a single result.

Comment: I think it's more likely here that the double-pointer is used as the C method of being able to change a pointer argument (which is better done with a reference in C++). But your solution should work either way.

Answer (score 1):

This functions expects a pointer to a `bool*`, so the only way to call it is to have an actual `bool*` object somewhere. Your solution is the only one.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a little differently.  I Think this is a bit cleaner:

```
void fun2(bool * pArr, int idx)
{
    *(pArr + idx) = true;

    return;
}


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    bool myArr[] = { false, false, true };

    fun2(myArr, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I was playing with this in my c++14 and it didn't let me directly access the elements with an indexer.  Maybe that changed at some point?  But I thought this is reasonable.

Edit, this is really better:

```
void fun3(bool pArr[], int idx)
{
    if (NULL == *pArr)
        return;

    pArr[idx] = false;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you change _tmain to main to follow the standard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a hack every time you call the function you can simply write a wrapper function:

```
void fun(bool** pArr, int idx)
{
    if(NULL == *pArr)
       return;

    (*pArr)[idx] = false;
}

void super_fun(bool* pArr, int idx)
{
    fun(&pArr, idx);
}

int main()
{
    bool myArr[] = { false, false, true };

    super_fun(myArr, 2);
}
```